# show that equality is true, is that correct?

Tags: real-analysis

> Solving the product
>
> $(a+ib) (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta )$, prove that:
>
> $a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta= \sqrt[ ]{a^2+b^2}\sin[\theta +\arctan
> > \frac{b}{a} ].$

$(a + ib) ( \cos \theta + i \sin \theta) $
is denoted by   $z = a+ ib $ and  $w = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta.$

$( a + ib) ( \cos \theta + i \sin \theta) = (a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta) + i(a  \sin \theta + b \cos \theta) $

Now since we are multiplying $zw$, then:

$$\arg (zw) = \arg z + \arg w,$$
where $\theta = \arg w, \arg z = \arctan \frac{b}{a}.$

$$zw = r (\cos r + \sin r ) $$ with
$r = \theta + \arctan \frac{b}{a}= 1 $
$ =|a + ib| | \cos \theta + i \sin \theta| ( \cos r + i \sin r)  $
$ = \sqrt[ ]{a^2 + b^2} ( \cos r + i \sin r ),$ luego

$( a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta ) + i( a \sin \theta  + b \cos \theta ) = \sqrt[ ]{a^2 + b ^2} (\cos r + i \sin r) $

by equating the real part of the imaginary.

$a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta = \sqrt[ ]{a^2+ b^2} \sin r$
$ a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta = \sqrt[ ]{a^2+b^2} \sin  (\theta + \arctan  (\frac{b}{a})$

Comment: the part shaded in red are the corrections? my exercise was not quite right?